# Wordpress: Category Based Random Shortcode from Array

Tags: php, wordpress, random, conditional-statements, shortcode

I am trying to generate some extra money for our single income family this holiday season by building an affiliate site to sell. However, after much research and little help from the WordPress forum:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/u...3#post-3318897

I am in desperate need of some PHP code to randomly select a do_shortcode from an array based on the conditional category - similar to the Widget Logic plugin but for shortcodes.

I am currenty using:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[asle id=15]"); ?>
```

in my single.php page at www.AvengersCollectibles.com/wp to display the shortcode for my "Azon Pro Shopping List" that appears at the bottom of my single post pages but need some code to randomly show 1 of 5 such lists from an array based on each of the 9 categories/characters.

Thus far, something like the following was recommended:

```
<?php $ids = array( 43, 15, 8 ); // Default

if (in_category('Captain America')):
   $ids = array( 15, 16, 17, 19, 20 );
elseif (in_category('Spiderman')):
   $ids = array( 35, 36, 37, 39, 50, 5, 70 );
elseif (in_category('Green Hornet')):
   $ids = array( 75, 6, 22, 49 );
endif;
$id = 0;
if ( ! $id ) {
   $key = array_rand( $ids, 1 );
   $id=$ids[$key];
   echo do_shortcode("[asle id=$id]");
}

?>
```

but I keep receiving the following error message:

Method Not Implemented
GET to /wp/wp-admin/theme-editor.php not supported.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I welcome all comments, concerns, or questions you may have.

PS: I will gladly offer access if necessary and a royalty upon my sale of the site if you are able to successfully solve this problem.

Comment: You should put curly braces around the code to be executed after your "if" and "elseif".

Comment: I thank you or your fast reply. If I understand correctly, more like this:

<?php $ids = array( 43, 15, 8 ); // Default

if (in_category('Captain America')):{
   $ids = array( 15, 16, 17, 19, 20 );
}
elseif (in_category('Spiderman')):{
   $ids = array( 35, 36, 37, 39, 50, 5, 70 );
}
elseif (in_category('Green Hornet')):{
   $ids = array( 75, 6, 22, 49 );
}
endif;
$id = 0;
if ( ! $id ) {
   $key = array_rand( $ids, 1 );
   $id=$ids[$key];
   echo do_shortcode("[asle id=$id]");
}

?>

Comment: @ChrisHerbert - [it is ok](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) without curly braces and that has nothing to do with the issue in question...

Comment: GWMO, based on my answer bellow: those errors are not from the code you are presenting. Unless it is in the Shortcode function, that is not shown in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

If I put this in my `functions.php`:

```
add_shortcode( 'asle', 'so_13771287_random_shortcode' );

function so_13771287_random_shortcode( $atts ) 
{
    return 'Random ID = ' . $atts['id'];
}
```

And your exact code in `single.php`:

```
<?php $ids = array( 43, 15, 8 ); // Default

if (in_category('Captain America')):
   $ids = array( 15, 16, 17, 19, 20 );
elseif (in_category('Spiderman')):
   $ids = array( 35, 36, 37, 39, 50, 5, 70 );
elseif (in_category('Green Hornet')):
   $ids = array( 75, 6, 22, 49 );
endif;
$id = 0;
if ( ! $id ) {
   $key = array_rand( $ids, 1 );
   $id=$ids[$key];
   echo do_shortcode("[asle id=$id]");
}
?>
```

***It does work for me.***
Yes, I created all super hero categories for testing.

The shortcode prints a random number from the correspondent category in each visited single post.

Comment: Dear brasofilo,

You are definitely a blessing this holiday season. It appears to function flawlessly – save for one minor problem.

I notice that when a new page is loading, I can see the function.php code at the top of the new page until it fully loads. I'm already using WP Super Cache, any other suggestions?

Comment: The code above that I added to my functions.php file in my child theme appears at the top of the screen for a brief 1-2 seconds each time a page is loaded:

Screenshot
http://www.avengerscollectibles.com/code.jpg